# Why does my counter not function properly when it should be 0, but other values >0 work fine?

Tags: c++, syntax

**What I'm trying to do**
Return an integer, which would represent the number of numbers that I would need to add in order to make my array consecutive (once its sorted, first).

**Sample input and output**
Input: [6, 2, 3, 8].
Output: 3.
Reason: After sorting the vector to [2, 3, 6, 8], we would need 3 numbers in order to make the whole vector consecutive (4, 5, 7 need to be added to the array, hence returning 3).

**Where am I at?**
Took care of a base-case of 1 integer in the vector (return 0; nothing to make consecutive).
Created a counter, set to 0.
Sorted the vector, ascending.
Loop through the vector, to check:
If the difference between the value on the right and the current value != 1, then add 1 to the counter. This would mean that the next number is not consecutive, and therefore we need a number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>


int makeArrayConsecutive2(std::vector<int> statues) {
    
    if (statues.size() == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    int counter = 0;
    std::sort(statues.begin(), statues.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < statues.size(); i++) {
        if (statues[i+1] - statues[i] != 1) {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    
    return counter;

}
```

**So what's the issue?**
4/5 of my test cases passed, ***except for this one***:

Input: [5, 4, 6]
Expected: 0
Actual: 1

I'm having trouble understanding why this is not working for that one case. If everything else is working, how come its just this one case? I suspect its an index issue, but I tried playing around with -1 from my indexes, and still not working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: perhaps I'm missing it, but how does this code account for jumps of more than 1 value? for example, in `[2, 3, 6, 8]` this loop would only increment `counter` twice: one for `3` and one for `6`. I would expect that taste case to fail.

Comment: following the previous, I suspect perhaps your code always adds one at the end due to comparing `statues[i+1]` past the end of the vector, which is probably UB

Comment: Yikes you're right. I think I would just need to add another for-loop starting at the 2nd index.

Comment: that doesn't seem elegant, I would just calculate the difference and add that minus one

Comment: `std::max(statuses)-std::min(statuses)+1-statuses.size()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library already provides `std::adjacent_difference`, which can do the vast majority of the work for you:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int makeArrayConsecutive(std::vector<int> input)
{
    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::vector<int> diffs;
    std::adjacent_difference(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(diffs));
    std::transform(diffs.begin(), diffs.end(), diffs.begin(), [](int a) { return a - 1; });
    int result = std::accumulate(diffs.begin() + 1, diffs.end(), 0);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << makeArrayConsecutive({ 6, 2, 3, 8 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << makeArrayConsecutive({ 5, 4, 6 });
}
```

Result (as expected):

```
3
0
```

Note: I've left each operation separate for clarity. You could (for one example) pretty easily eliminate the `std::transform` by using a functor with `std::accumulate` instead:

```
int makeArrayConsecutive(std::vector<int> input)
{
    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::vector<int> diffs;
    std::adjacent_difference(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(diffs));
    int result = std::accumulate(diffs.begin() + 1, diffs.end(),
                                 0,
                                 [](int total, int val) { return total + val - 1; });
    return result;
}
```

Likewise, you could eliminate the extra storage for the differences by writing the differences back into the input array, which could give a substantial reduction in storage requirements if the input was very big:

```
int makeArrayConsecutive(std::vector<int> input)
{
    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    std::adjacent_difference(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin());
    int result = std::accumulate(input.begin() + 1, input.end(),
                                 0,
                                 [](int total, int val) { return total + val - 1; });
    return result;
}
```

...but if you're just trying to figure out what's going on, I think the first version is probably the simplest to follow.

Answer (score 2):

These are the corrected lines:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < statues.size()-1; i++) {
        if (statues[i+1] - statues[i] != 1) {
            counter += statues[i+1] - statues[i] -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept this. However before I do so, could you explain to me why we would want to add 2 of the numbers from the vector to the counter? Then subtract 1? Losing me there.

Comment: @Z41N Ex. if you have "3,6", then you need 2 values (4 and 5), therefore (6-3)-1

Comment: @anastaciu mmhhh it outputs 3 on my side ... How come it outputs 2 on yours ?

Comment: @Necklondon I meant why are we subtracting ```statues[i+1]``` and ```statues[i]``` and 1? They're actual numbers from the vector, and they could (or could not) be the max/min, so why those specific ones? Also @anastaciu - this does work with the first case, you may have it wrong.

Comment: @Z41N Let's take the simplest case, suppose you have "3,4". Then you would NOT output 1, would you ? Because there is nothing missing. So you must substract 1.

Comment: Ahhh got it, thanks you @Necklondon. Understood now, will accept your answer. Best